# Opencart Redirect 301 with "/" in the end

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart, slash

I wrote this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=test$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.ru/main/? [R=301,L]
```

This redirect works if I type URL without slash in the end: `mysite.ru/test`, but this: `mysite.ru/test/` doesn't work, could you help me plz?